Print every few seconds in while loop
I have a loop in my test.c who will do several things, e.g.
int main()
{
 ...do things...
     int calculate=0;
     while(x <=10000) {
      ...operation on calculate...;
      x++;
      //print calculate every 'x' seconds
    };
 return 0;
}

What I need to do is find a way to output the "calculate" variable every "x" seconds, e.g. every 5 seconds, obviously without using sleep as I need my loop continues. Could someone advise with the approach I could use?

(1) You can add thread that wake up every 5 seconds and prints the value (2) If you don't want to use a thread, you can take time measurements every n iterations (n requires calibratin) and check if 5 seconds passed since the last print.

I'm still using a threads, as my loop is in a thread. Do you have any example for time measurements to be applied in my case?

If you want to add a thread you can simply make it sleep for 5 seconds. But note that using multiple thread will required to synchronize access to the data to print.

If you'd like a thread to do the printing, you need synchronization. You could use a mutex or atomic variables. I've used atomic variables in this example.
First a struct to share with the thread, telling it if it should keep running and what the current value of calculate is:
struct data {
    atomic_bool run;
    atomic_uint calculate;
};

You then need to supply your printing thread with a pointer to such a struct. In the thread, you'd simply loop while run is true, sleep for 5 seconds and print calculate:
int printer(void *userdata) {
    struct data* dat = userdata;
    const struct timespec dur = {5, 0};
    while(dat->run) {
        thrd_sleep(&dur, NULL);         // sleep for 5 seconds
        printf("%d\n", dat->calculate);
    }
    return 0;
}

Full example:
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <threads.h>

struct data {
    atomic_bool run;
    atomic_uint calculate;
};

int printer(void *userdata) {
    struct data* dat = userdata;
    const struct timespec dur = {5, 0};

    while(dat->run) {
        thrd_sleep(&dur, NULL);
        printf("%u\n", dat->calculate);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    struct data dat = {true, 0};
    thrd_t thr;
    thrd_create(&thr, printer, &dat);

    const struct timespec dur = {0, 1000000};
    for(int x = 0; x < 10000; ++x) {
        thrd_sleep(&dur, NULL); // simulate some work being done
        ++dat.calculate;
    }
    dat.run = false; // makes the thread end in up to after 5 seconds

    puts("joining thread");
    int res;
    thrd_join(thr, &res);
}


Simply check how much time passed like in this example:
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 int main()
{
    clock_t start, end;
 
    /* Recording the starting clock tick.*/
    start = clock();

    unsigned x = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        x++;
        if(clock() - start >= CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 10)
        {
            // print x after every 1/10 of seconds
            start = clock();
            printf("x = %u\n", x);
            fflush(stdout);

        }
    }
}

https://godbolt.org/z/48W81Ebbx
(fflush is needed by godbolt to transfer the line to the browser)
You do need to check at every iteration, the code is only showing thew simplest idea of archiving it)
